# Bayesian and frequency tail estimation

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, extreme-value, method-comparison

The tail probability can be estimated by two methods:

1. In Bayesian method:
   $$P_B(X>a)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\pi(\theta|x)[1-F(a|\theta)]d\theta$$
2. In Plug-in frequency method:
   $$P_F(X>a)=1-F(a|\hat{\theta})$$
   where $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE of $\theta$.

The numerical results show that it's always $$P_B \geq P_F$$
no matter what the distribution is.

Any ideas or any resources related to this topic to explain why is that?

Answer (score 2):

First note that $P_B(X > a)$ is the value of the survival function of
the *predictive distribution*, which is a mixture of distributions
taken in the parametric family considered, the mixture weight being the
posterior density.

I do not think that the result is always true, that is: *for any distribution*,
*for any sample*, and *for any $a$*. However, the predictive
distribution has tail which is thicker than any parametric
distribution in the posterior which means that the inequality holds
for large $a$. Under quite general conditions, the ML estimate $\hat{\theta}$
is in the support of the posterior, and the claimed
relation should hold for large $a$. The reason is
that *a mixture of continuous distributions has a tail which is
heavier than that of its components*. I wrote some details in [this
answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/339820/10479) to an
apparently quite different question.

To get a counterexample we can choose a prior such that the ML
estimate $\hat{\theta}$ does not always belong to it. For example
consider an exponential distribution with mean $\theta$ assumed to lie
in $(0, \, 1)$. If it happens that $\hat{\theta} > 1$ then
the inequality will not hold.